# IdentityServer4 authenticating against an external api

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, identityserver4

We have a requirement to authenticate users in IdentityServer4 against an external API. The scenario works like this:

1. User visits a Javascript client application and clicks the login button to redirect to IdentityServer login page (exact same client as provided in the docs [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/4_javascript_client.html)
2. User enters their username (email) and password
3. IdentityServer4 connects to an external API to verify credentials
4. User is redirected back to the JavaScript application

The above process works perfect when using the TestUsers provided in the QuickStarts. However, when an API is used, the login page resets and does not redirect the user back to the JavaScript client. The only change is the below code and a custom implementation of IProfileService.

Below is the custom code in the login action (showing only the relevant part):

```
            var apiClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("API");
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/api/auth");

            var loginModel = new LoginModel
            {
                Email = model.Email,
                Password = model.Password
            };
            var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loginModel), 
                                                Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            request.Content = content;

            HttpResponseMessage result = await apiClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false);

            var loginStatus = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiLoginStatus>(
                                    await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

            if (loginStatus.LoginSuccess)
            {
                await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(model.Email, model.Email, loginStatus.Name, clientId: context?.ClientId));

                AuthenticationProperties props = null;
                if (AccountOptions.AllowRememberLogin && model.RememberLogin)
                {
                    props = new AuthenticationProperties
                    {
                        IsPersistent = true,
                        ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(AccountOptions.RememberMeLoginDuration)
                    };
                };

                var user = new IdentityServerUser(loginStatus.SubjectId)
                {
                    DisplayName = loginStatus.Name
                };

                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(user, props);
                if (context != null)
                {
                    if (await _clientStore.IsPkceClientAsync(context.ClientId))
                    {
                        return View("Redirect", new RedirectViewModel { RedirectUrl = model.ReturnUrl });
                    }

                    return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                }
```

The code actually hits the return View() path, but for some reason it resets and the login page is shown again.

Code in Startup.cs:

```
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.Ids)
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.Apis)
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients) 
            .AddProfileService<ProfileService>()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
```

Code in ProfileService.cs:

```
public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
{
    var profile = await GetUserProfile(context.Subject.GetSubjectId());

    var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, profile.Email),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, profile.Name)
        };

    context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(claims);
}

public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
{
    var profile = await GetUserProfile(context.Subject.GetSubjectId());
    context.IsActive = (profile != null);
}
```

There are multiple sources online that show how to user a custom store for authentication, but they all seem to use ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator. If someone could point out what is missing here, it would help greatly. Thanks.

Comment: Given that you say it's hitting the "Redirect" view, and that view is very simple (just a meta refresh), have you confirmed that the ReturnUrl value being passed in is what you expect?  You may want to watch the network traffic with something like Fiddler to ensure that only one redirect is actually happening.  Could it be possible that it is actually correctly redirecting you back to your SPA and then somehow that is bouncing you back to the login page (in a redirect loop)?

Comment: @BryanLewis thanks for your response. I did check the redirects and everything is setup correctly. The issue turned out to be something else as mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue turned out to be very simple. We had missed removing the builder.AddTestUsers(TestUsers.Users) line when setting up IdentityServer in Startup.cs.

Looking at the code [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4/src/Test/IdentityServerBuilderExtensions.cs), it turned out that this line was overriding our profile service with the test users profile service. Removing that line solved the problem.